# Autolayout two views vertically with dynamic height aligned top

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have two views that can be dynamic height.
Dependent on content either view1 or view2 is the highest.

The highest view should determinate the distance to view3.

In my current implementation view1 and view2 each have a constraint for x pixels for view3. But the problem is view1 and view2 then always will be same height (all the content will not align top)

[image]

Comment: Some clarification: When you say highest, do you mean tallest (so the height of view 1 and view 2 can vary independently)? And that the distance from the tallest view (1 or 2) to view 3 should be constant?

Comment: Yes view1 and view2 height can vary independently. The height from the tallest view(1 or 2) should be a constant to view3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this. Make sure both views 1 and 2, have some constraint to the top of the superview and to the sides (or fixed width, whatever it takes to fix the views in the horizontal direction). Lets say you want that distance to the bottom view to be 30. Give view 1 a constraint to view 3 of =30 with a priority of 200, and another one of >=30 with a priority of 1000 (default). View 2 should just need one constraint to view 3 of >=30 with 1000 priority.

The low priority constraint (of 200) will fix the position of view 3 initially, but is low enough that if view 2 expands, view 3 will move down, and also low enough that the default Content Hugging Priority of view 1 will keep it from expanding its height if it doesn't need to based on its text size.

Comment: Thanks i was going in the direction of your answer but i did not use two vertical constraints between view 1 and 3.

Comment: I can't find good documentation of what you're describing. Can you provide a code sample of the constraints you're recommending here? I realize how long it's been since you've answered this, but I'm running into a similar situation and I can't figure out a good solution.

Comment: @Matt, the written documentation doesn't go into a lot of detail, so you should look at the WWDC 2012 videos (there are 3) concerning auto layout for more information. If this answer doesn't give you enough detail to fix your problem, you should ask a question of your own. I don't really know what code I would show you without more information.

Comment: Thanks. A few minutes after posting my comment I found the documentation for VFL [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html). It helped, but wasn't able to answer all my questions.

Comment: rdelmar, do you think something similar to your answer can be applied to my question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658526/using-autolayout-to-stack-to-columns-of-varying-heights?

Answer (score 0):

**swift**

```
    import SnapKit

    view3.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(view1.snp.bottom).offset(30)
        $0.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(view2.snp.bottom).offset(30)
        $0.left.right.equalTo(0)
        $0.height.equalTo(50)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways actually

1. With constraints (as described rdelmar)

```swift
class MyViewController: ViewController {
    let view1 = View()
    let view2 = View()
    let view3 = View()

    override func buildUI() {
        super.buildUI()
        body {
            view1
                .edgesToSuperview(top: 16, leading: 16)
            view2
                .edgesToSuperview(top: 16, trailing: -16)
                .width(to: view1)
                .leadingTo(view1, 16)
            view3
                .topTo(view1, 30 ! 200) // 200 is priority, ! is priority operator
                .topTo(view2, >=30)
                .edgesToSuperview(leading: 16, trailing: -16, bottom: -16)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure here about =30 with 200 priority, maybe it should be >=30 as with view2, but you can easily figure it out with [Live preview](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlusExample)

2. With StackViews

```swift
class MyViewController: ViewController {
    override func buildUI() {
        super.buildUI()
        body {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    View() // view 1
                    View() // view 2
                }
                .distribution(.fillEqually) // to make view 1&2 width equally
                .alignment(.top)
                Space() // flexible space
                VSpace(30) // fixed 30pt height space
                View() // view 3
            }
            .edgesToSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

All the examples are by using awesome [UIKitPlus](https://github.com/MihaelIsaev/UIKitPlus) library

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer did not work for me (although it did put me on the right path). In my case, view 1 or view 2 could be any size and view 3 had to be below the highest one. This code got it to work, though I must say I find autolayout extremely unintuitive:

```
let view3TopAnchor1 = statusL.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0)
view3TopAnchor1.priority = UILayoutPriority(100)
view3TopAnchor1.isActive = true

let view3TopAnchor2 = statusL.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: view2.bottomAnchor, constant: 10.0)
view3TopAnchor2.priority = UILayoutPriority(100)
view3TopAnchor2.isActive = true

view1.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(101), for: .vertical)
view2.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(101), for: .vertical)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
float yPos = MAX(view1.frame.size.height,view2.frame.size.height);

view3.frame.origin.y = view1.frame.origin.y + maxHeight;
```

Comment: I cant change the frame when using autolayout.
I have thought about making custom constraints dependent on the content.