# sizeToFit() returns wrong height - Need to find cell width in heightForRow

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to make a UITableView with dynamic cell heights, based on the content. My app is an article viewer. I try to calculate the height of the cells with these functions.

```
func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let post = FeedController.sharedController.allPosts[indexPath.row]
    var height = 16.0
    if post.hasImage {
        height += Double(self.view.frame.width) / (4/3)
    }

    let titleH = heightForView(post.title!, font: UIFont(name: "LiberationSerif-Bold", size: 20.0)!, width: self.tableView.bounds.width)
    let descH = heightForView(post.desc!, font: UIFont(name: "LiberationSerif", size: 17.0)!, width: self.tableView.bounds.width)

    let totalHeight = CGFloat(height+Double(titleH)+Double(descH))

    print("imageH: \(height), titleH: \(titleH) detailH: \(descH) totalH:\(totalHeight)")
    return totalHeight
}
```

When I run it, it looks like this, as you can see, the bottom label is cut off.

[image]

I ran it trough the interface breakpoint thingy, where you can see the cause of the error:

[image]

The rendered size is one size larger than the estimated size from sizeToFit(), as you can see from my log statement:

```
imageH: 297.25, titleH: 44.5 detailH: 56.5 totalH:398.25
```

I suspect the reason for this calculation error is due to me providing the heightForView function with the wrong width parameter. I have tried to use tableView.contentSize, and many other things. The lineBreakMode is the same in my storyboard and in my code.

I guess what I need is a better way to find the expected width of the cell, or any other solution which will give me the proper expected height.

---

**Edit: Constraints:** 
[image]

Comment: May I suggest Autolayout? It does all that work for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658526/using-autolayout-to-stack-within-two-columns-of-varying-heights/31804168#31804168

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I tried with the solution you described in that thread, but auto layout does not seem to be able to resize cell height properly. I added my constraints to my latest edit to the post, if you could take a look and tell me what I did wrong, I would be grateful.

Comment: I got a temp solution to this using a magic number to get the content offset from the table view width (8). Bad solution, but it works now. Still looking for proper answers.

Comment: Are you using or missing "relative to margin"? Are you using a `XIB` or a `storyboard`?

Comment: I'm using a storyboard, and I guess yes. How does one do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Automatic Dimension

With much less code(*), you can ditch `heightForRowAtIndexPath` entirely, and use `autolayout` for everything.

1. Do not overwrite `heightForRowAtIndexPath` (all that code goes away)
2. Tell the table view to do the hard work (in `viewDidLoad` for example):

```swift
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

*(*) **2 lines** of code, to be precise.*
Convince yourself by comparing [2 lines solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440422/218152) against [multiple methods override solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24166645/218152).

---

**Notes on margin**

- `XIB` & `storyboard`: you have the ability to control the constraints and their relationships to margin.
  Note that when using *Relative to margin*, the item order matters, as margins are generally insets.
  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420909/218152 for some details.
- `storyboard`: you have access to the additional `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` properties from **IB**, which may be of value for your view controller, but are off-topic for your `UITableViewCell`.