# iOS Expanded/Selected Custom UITableViewCells state changes when scrolling UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitableview

I have a list of custom cells in my tableview and as I scroll everything appears to fine and the cells appear to be in the same order. I have some functionality with my cells - as i select a cell (and it dynamically expands)the background color changes and a few other custom cell properties. Once I do this and then I start scrolling, different cells that i haven't even touched before show up, selected(expanded) and the cell only updates when I select it manually to the correct data. I seem to see duplicates and all kinds of craziness.

I know there are LOTS of posts about this on here so far but for me, so far nothing has worked. Would like some input on what I could do to stop this ridiculous behavior.

I have posted some code to give you a better idea of what I am doing. I know that 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier' is the culprit but don't know of an alternative.

As side notes, this is a tableview(its own xib) that is a child view of a large view (also a xib). I have also already registered the nib for the tableview.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(self.currentSelectedIndex){

        if(self.previousSelectedIndex){
                //collapse cell
                //configure cell in method(change background color etc)
         }
        else{
         //expand cell
         //configure cell in method(change background color etc)
         }
     }

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.currentSelectedIndex = indexPath;

   [tableView beginUpdates];
    if(self.currentSelectedIndex){
        if(self.previousSelectedIndex && (self.previousSelectedIndex != self.currentSelectedIndex)){
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.currentSelectedIndex, self.previousSelectedIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
        else{
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.currentSelectedIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];

    if(self.previousSelectedIndex == self.currentSelectedIndex){
        self.previousSelectedIndex = nil;
    }
    else{
        self.previousSelectedIndex = self.currentSelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

What can I do or how would i make sure that nothing else in the list 'seems' to be selected(expanded) or prevent from appearing to see duplicates as i scroll? I already keep track of my current and last selected index(as shown in the code) so I suppose that I could use that somehow?

Comment: ill add this here as well - just as a tidbit. tried it with 1 cell in the tableview. its collapsed. When i swipe up fast and it comes back into view its expanded magically. only when i interact with it does it go back to its original state.

Comment: Update: I think i found my problem. I was playing around with that one cell - and it turns out that when selecting a cell and the previousIndexPath was equal to the new currentIndexPath i wasn't setting the currentIndexPath back to nil (no selections - everything back at default state). so when reloading the tableview in any way(scrolling, pull up or down etc) it still thought that there was a selectedIndex - and my logic at that point failed. but good to know that you CAN do it, just have to be careful :) thanks for the help though, I'm keeping your original linked post handy.

Answer (score 0):

**Dequeued Cells are Reused**

Know that cells are re-used, so that the appearance of a `UITableViewCell` is persistent for the entire life of that cell.

This means that if you do not explicitly `reset` all the presentation view of your cell, and just returning it unchanged in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, what you are returning may be a currently selected (or deselected) cached cell.

A possible location to reset a table cell is `prepareForReuse`.

---

Design note:
How are you maintaining `self.currentSelectedIndex` and `self.previousSelectedIndex`? This is typically quite dangerous, since you are attempting to replicate the `UITableView` behavior. It is for example, unlikely to work with multiple selection. Setting an *active* selection is unlikely handle situations when the OS `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`, as a result of a keyboard dismissal for example.

Comment: in didSelectRowAtIndexPath - I added that code for you to look at. Basically, every time i select an index i set that to the current one. This should take every case into account - selecting a index for the very first time, selecting the same cell twice in a row(previous and current are the same) and selecting a current index then selecting a different index right after that. Let me know if you have any questions or if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Yeah in my case, to answer your updated response, there can be only one 'selected/expanded' cell at a time. If you have a cell that is expanded that you select a different cell the previous cell is collapsed and the new cell is expanded. So there are no multiple selections at once.

Comment: is using didSelect/didDeselect as ways to reload those rows specifically enough to solve the issue? That link seems to suggest so. As an example, in my case, if the previousIndex is not equal to the current Index after making a selection then we know that that they are different indexes.. the previous row should be deSelected and the new selected one is to be selected.

Comment: you said above " Reset color/fonts/look of the cell being returned to you.." I am not sure what you mean here...?

Comment: I am also using heightForRowAtIndexPath to keep track of my current and previous selected index for the purpose of expanding/collapsing. This might not need to be touched I am not sure..I can give you that code too if you want. It really mimics cellForRowAtIndexPath in the sense of checking all cases - i,,e (if its the first selected index so far, expand the cell, if not, did you touch the same index twice in a row(previous = current)? - then collapse the cell, if you select a cell and previous != current then expand the new index, collapse the previous..

Comment: **Comment #1**: stackoverflow.com/a/34997679/218152 is better, since is will cover spurious deselection, like selection cancelled by an OS event, keyboard dismiss, tap-drag-outside, etc. You should follow that link & +1 if it works for you. **Comment #2**: Everything to do to a cell is persistent ; when you `dequeue` a cell, assume everything is wrong with it (it is likely one that just went offscreen), so clean it as if it had come from a resource. **Comment #3**: You will be so much better off using estimatedRowHeight and change a constraint. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34778194/218152