# Passing data to custom UITableViewCell with adding subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm passing data to a custom UITableViewCell and based on that data I want to show or hide a dynamically added subview. I'm reusing a cell which is created in the storyboard. Everything is working as expected, until some of the cells are reused, for example while scrolling it will "randomly" hide or show the dynamic added subview.

***What I need***

I need a way to set the data of a cell through a method (setData), adding a dynamically created subview, while allowing a cell to be reused without creating glitches in its appearance, in particular the added subview as well the cells  state.

***Problem***

I don't know where I should create the subview, so it doesn't have to be recreated when the cell is reused and so it won't bug when I want to hide or show it in the setData method. As well having access to the IBOutlet storyboardLabel while creating the new subview.

CustomTableViewCell

```
class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
   var data: DataItem?
   var customSubview: UIView?

   @IBOutlet weak var storyboardLabel: UILabel!

   //setting the data of a cell and adding the subview
   func setData(DataItem data) {
      // adding the view
      let customSubview = UIView.init(...)
      customSubview.bounds = storyboardLabel.bounds
      customSubview.hidden = data.showSubview
      self.contentView.addSubview(customSubview)
   }
}
```

Adding the cell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("storyboardTableCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.setData(self.data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! DataItem)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at `prepareForReuse()` already?

Comment: I did actually, but I'm looking for a solution without recreating the subview, if there is any. Because in my opinion it seems a bit unnecessary to recreate it when its reused.

Comment: What you could do is lazily create the subview and in `prepareForReuse` check if it exists and hide it. I think SwiftArchitect explanations should be enough but if you still need help I can show you how.

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help and I'm using prepareForReuse now. Have a nice evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything is working as expected, until some of the cells are reused...

Nothing is working as expected: you are adding object to a cached `UITableViewCell`, and of course, when you are passed that cached cell again on a subsequent `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you are adding new objects.

*Consider using a collection of views in **IB**, each satisfying your cell organization, thus saving adding subviews programmatically.*

You need to clean up your cell.

- Either remove everything you have added in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

  - You can use `tags` and `viewWithTag` if you want to refrain from re-adding already existing views
- Or implement `prepareForReuse()`

---

You can find an example (and a similar discussion) on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35238247/218152).